# How to add new node just after parent node in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am combining three xml documents into one using C# XML and Linq. Before I want to save it as a "Final.xml" I want to add a `<New>` node under the parent node and at the bottom before the closing parent node.

I have a XML structure like this:

```
<Main>
   <Action>
      <URL />
   </Action>
   <Execute>
      <URL />
      <MetaData />
   </Execute>
   <Action>
      <URL />
   </Action>
   <Assert>
      <URL />
   </Assert>
</Main>
```

I want to add a new node under the `<Main>` node and above the`</Main>` node. The new Scructure needs to look like this:

```
<Main>
  <New>
    <Action>
      <URL />
   </Action>
   <Execute>
      <URL />
      <MetaData />
   </Execute>
   <Action>
      <URL />
   </Action>
   <Assert>
      <URL />
   </Assert>
  </New>
</Main>
```

I've tried code like:

```
...
var xelem3 = xdoc4.Root.Elements();
xdoc1.Root.LastNode.AddAfterSelf(xelem3);

var Tests = xdoc1.Root.Elements("Test");


foreach (var test in Tests)
  {
    test.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("New"));
  }

   xdoc1.Save(FinalDoc);
```

This does not work, It runs but nothing happens. I don't think a loop is the best way and I am wondering is there a better way. I have looked around but I don't seem to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Monica, do you think your question was answered? If no, please guide us on how we can help you. But if you think that your question has an answer, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I would recommend using `XDocument` (LINQ to XML) instead of `XmlDocument` (used with .NET version 3.0 or lower), because it's a much newer and very simple to use.

> For more information check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb387021(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) official doc.

And, so, by using `XDocument`, here is how simple can be the solution:

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Main>
    <Action>
        <URL />
    </Action>
    <Execute>
        <URL />
        <MetaData />
    </Execute>
    <Action>
        <URL />
    </Action>
    <Assert>
        <URL />
    </Assert>
</Main>");

var mainCopy = new XElement(doc.Root.Name); // creating an empty copy of the "Main" node
doc.Root.Name = "New"; // replace the "Main" with "New"

doc = new XDocument(new XElement(mainCopy.Name, doc.Root)); // creating a wrapper XML
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are far more fancy solutions but. this works:

```
var xmlstring = "<Root><Child1>1</Child1><Child2>2</Child2><Child3>3</Child3></Root>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

var childs = doc.Root.Elements().ToList();
doc.Root.RemoveAll();

var parent = new XElement("Parent");
parent.Add(childs);

doc.Root.Add(parent);
```